# How can i find and change css style in ruby?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know much about ruby, but I know about html and css...

In my Ruby on Rails application I have this tag:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin.css", "jquery.facebox.css", "jquery.tooltip.css" %>
```

Which has the output of this (i only show the css, i need css only):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/admin.css?1391082652">
```

But not exist this path "/stylesheets" in my aplication, i found the file admin.css only here:

```
/home/webserver/app/public/stylesheets

/home/webserver/app/app/stylesheets
```

when I rename it to "**admin.css_**", the css styles continues to apper normal in html ruby, even clear cache in browser.

How I can change the css and make work correctly in website?

Do I need to compile anything?

Not only overwrite the file somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can add extra css in your application with .css in /home/webserver/app/public/stylesheets

Another is that css are you applying is directly from jQuery  I think so

Please inspect the in browser and check the class name

then search in your application with ctr+f

Comment: sanket, tell me one think... change css in ruby its easy? only overwrite the file and done all work?

i finded all this place but not work:

/home/webserver/app/public/stylesheets

/home/webserver/app/app/stylesheets

/home/webserver/rails_origem/rails/public/stylesheets

/home/webserver/rails_origem/rails/app/stylesheets

Comment: sanket, i cant change the ruby files, and i dont want, I just want to change the admin.css. :)

Comment: i am m=not asking to change ruby files only add new css and call in view page

Comment: i finded the right place and file... /home/webserver/app/public/stylesheets... thanks sanket to your help.